# Symfony command finding folder

Tags: windows, symfony, terminal, command

I am trying to call command using symfony Process and command looks like:

```
$data = escapeshellarg("public\uploads\post_data.txt");
$url = "www.example.com/";
$process = new Process(['ab -n 10 -p '.$data.' -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded -w '. $url . 'test/send']);
$process->run();
```

When i call this command from terminal it works fine but when i try to call it using symfony command then i am getting:
`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` This error is windows terminal error as i know and i think the problem is with `\` but i have tried to change it to `\\`, `//` and `/` but not helped.

Comment: Try with escapeshellargs() -> http://php.net/manual/de/function.escapeshellarg.php and maybe its not a bad idea to use sprintf to build your shellcommand string.

Comment: @rebru tried. nothing changed. same error.

Comment: Can you show the whole command in symfony (the execute method)? Whats about, when you dump the $variable thats holding the shellcmd, is it in correct format?

Comment: @rebru updated question. added execute. when i dump data it shows me correct format.

Comment: Accordingly to the documentation, i would say, thats not possible with your approach. I would say, you have to use the Process::fromShellCommandline method described here -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Under Using Features From the OS Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, your approach doesnt work, because new Process needs to be defined in a array, where each piece of the shellcmd is a entry in the array.

So for your case, you should have to write

```
$process = new Process(['ab', '-n', 10, '-p', $data, '-T', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', '-w', $url.'test/send']);
```

Or try with the fromShellCommandline static function

```
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('ab -n 10 -p '.$data.' -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded -w '. $url . 'test/send');
```

Comment: yes exactly. i have used it before but declared wrong. after your comment about `fromShellCommandline` i have tried it again and now it works. perfect. thank you :)